# Trying to understand, how jQuery .css function in native javascript?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, javascript

External CSS file...

```
#externalClass { font-family: arial; }
```

HTML file...

```
<a href="#" id="externalClass">Link</a>
```

JavaScript file...

```
console.log(jQuery("#externalClass").css("font-family"));
```

I get the "arial", but not able to understand how it's working (even in IE6/7/8/9) in native javascript?

Can someone explain it please.

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery source code?

Comment: Read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) (with necessary fallbacks such as [`currentStyle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to calculate the `font-family` value.

[Source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L285).

When you're wondering how a library achieves something, the best way is to look at the source, and if you're stuck comprehending it, then Google more or ask here :)

Answer (score 0):

There is exists `style` property for DOM element, where you can get or set needed CSS styles. In your case - `document.getElementById("externalClass").style.fontFamily`

Comment: yes it's work while set CSS property to DOM, but what if need to know, what CSS already applied?